# Estimating the probability that a sample follows a normal distribution in R

Tags: r, probability

I have a sample of multiple data points in R. How would I go about estimating the probability that this sample follows a normal distribution? Do I use pnorm?

Comment: Hi MTJN317 and welcome to SO ! Can you be more specific about your data ? You could e.g share it using `dput(your_data)` so that we can check if it is 1D data, ...
Moreover you can improve your question following this post : [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I voted to migrate your question to Cross Validated (**stats.stackexchange**), because this is where it should be asked, since it is highly statistics related. There's no probability that a sample follows a normal distribution (except in some non-elementary Bayesian contexts). You can do a normality test, as suggested by @Almog5690 in his answer. You should get more comments on Cross Validated.

Comment: The general sentiment on Cross Validated is that such testing is unhelpful. You either find yourself without enough data to be able to reject, or you have so much data that you reject based on a real but tiny, unimportant difference. Further, getting in the "sweet spot" for sample size might not even correspond to the needed sample size of the real test you want to do (t-test, for instance). We advocate for visual examination of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you want:

```
shapiro.test(sample)
```

This function preform the Shapiro-Wilk test, a test to see if a variable is normally distributed.